# How to wait for multiple responses in Playwright [typescript]

Tags: typescript, async-await, wait, playwright, playwright-typescript

We have a method in Playwright to wait for a response.

```
page.waitForResponse
```

But, I need to wait for multiple responses using waitForResponse. How can we achieve this?

I have tried looping the waitForResponse method, but that doesn't work.

Update:
Code I tried:

```
 async click(locator: string, waitForResponse){
 // waitForResponse = [{url: 'url1'},{url: 'url3'},{url: 'url2'}];
    const [response] = await Promise.all([
            waitForResponse ? this._waitForResponse(waitForResponse) : Promise.resolve(true),
            await this.page.locator(locator).first().click()
          ]);
    }
// Calling function
 await click(`xpath`, [{url: 'url1'},{url: 'url3'},{url: 'url2'}]);
```

waitForResponse method:
WaitForResponse is a type here.

```
public async _waitForResponse(args: WaitForResponse | Array<WaitForResponse>): Promise<any> {
if (Array.isArray(args)) {
  const resposneArray = [];
  for (const aa in args) {
    resposneArray.push(await this._callWaitForResponse(args[aa]));
  }
  return resposneArray;
} else {
  return this._callWaitForResponse(args);
}
```

}

actual waitForResponse method:

```
private async _callWaitForResponse(args: WaitForResponse): Promise<any> {
const { requestUrl } = args;
return this.page.waitForResponse((response) =>
  requestUrl.every((url: string) => response.url().includes(url))
);
```

}

Comment: "I have tried looping the waitForResponse method, but that doesn't work." -- that's the way to do it. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please share your code to show what you have tried so far to get faster and precise responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (please regard it as pseudo code though, I haven't had time to test it):

```
async clickAndWaitForResponses(locator: string, urlsToWaitFor: string[]) {
    const allResponsesPromise = Promise.all(urlsToWaitFor.map(url => page.waitForResponse(url)));
    await this.page.locator(locator).first().click();
    const responses = await allResponsesPromise;
}

// Calling function
await clickAndWaitForResponses(`xpath`, ['url1', url3', 'url2']);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Keep in mind JavaScript is `async` before using any loops.

[How to use asyc-await with loops?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

---

In general, you may wait for multiple responses with an handy `custom` function something like below using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
async waitForResponseCustom(resName) {
    return await this.page.waitForResponse(async (response) => {
        const body = await response.text();
        return body.includes(resName)
    });
}
    const responses = await Promise.all([
        this.waitForResponseCustom("API 1"),
        this.waitForResponseCustom("API 2")
      
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @vishal-aggarwal.

This is fine. But what the users will be sending is, `[{url: 'url'},{url: 'url2'}]`.

as in,

he will be calling method as,
`urlArrays = [{url: 'url'},{url: 'url2'}, {url: 'url3'}]`
`waitForResponseCustom(urlArrays);`

And this can be many urls. I was thinking of writing a generic method to wait for all urls.

Comment: @Ray , can you share the code under discussion as currently its all talk. Let us see what you have tried so far and where you are stuck in ~code~.

Comment: I have added my codes @vishal

Answer (score 0):

So, I have done most of the code, but was struggling to solve it.

Now I got it.

Here,s the answer.

```
public async _waitForResponse(args: WaitForResponse | Array<WaitForResponse>): Promise<any> {
if (Array.isArray(args)) {
  const responseArray = [];
  for (const arg of args) {
    const response = this._callWaitForResponse(arg);
    responseArray.push(response);
  }
  return Promise.all(responseArray); // This is what i have missed.
} else {
  return this._callWaitForResponse(args);
}
```

}