# Deal with multiple redirections

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I need a playwright test for a login flow that behaves like this:

1. I'm in the page login form of Server 2, where I fill the form and click `Sign In` which triggers a post request to Server 2 url `/login`
2. Server 2 returns 200 for `/login` url with a html response.
3. Page loads and a javascript code automatically triggers a navigation to Server 1 url `/signin-saml`.
4. Request to `/signin-saml` is executed and Server 1 returns 302 with location to Server 1 url `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback`.
5. `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` must load correctly including some fields.

I have tried different ways to get a 100% reliable test without luck so far. The test fails at different navigation points, saying that the navigation didn't happen.
I have tried, for example, 3 await waitForUrl statements in a row playing with the timeouts and waitUntil arguments, and also a waitForTimeout using a long enough time followed by a waitForUrl(`/Account/ExternalLoginCallback`). I haven't tried anything with waitForNavigation since it appears as deprecated in the current version of playwright that I'm using.

I need a way to test the described scenario with a reliable test. What is the best way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the page you're manipulating and your code attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing as I could find a solution. Based on the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206330/how-to-wait-for-multiple-responses-in-playwright-typescript), I changed the await waitForUrl(...) statements for an await Promise.all(...) passing all the awaits as arguments and also, added a delay to the click event before the navigation to make sure the navigations didn't occur before waiting for them.